# How to print Azure Pipeline variable to file using Command line task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using command line task inside Azure build pipeline to append list of last commit messages inside a text file.

But when trying to get pipeline variable value to text file it prints strange content (file names inside my project) instead of variable value. Is my syntax correct?

```
echo *** Version $(versionnumber) ***>> Release_Notes.txt
```

Agent pool is `Hosted Ubuntu 1604`.

Comment: I have to wait until next release to test it. Once done I'll update the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should include the content in double quotes, both of these command script works fine:

```
echo "*** Version $(versionnumber) ***" >> Release_Notes.txt
echo "*** Version $VERSIONNUMBER ***" >> Release_Notes.txt
```

Note: All pipeline variables will be convert to uppercase and variables are case sensitive in Ubuntu machine, so you need to use `$VERSIONNUMBER` to read environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Because you use Linux agent you should use Bash script and not Command Line script. in the bash the syntax is `$variable`:

```
echo *** Version $versionnumber *** >> Release_Notes.txt
```